# How do I tell cin to not allow spaces on input? (C++)

Tags: c++, string, memory, input, cin

When this runs I want to not be able to enter any spaces in `cin` what format specifier can I use for this?

Is their anything in `<string>` that lets me do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string yy;
    cin >> string;

    /*when this runs I want to not be able to enter any spaces in `cin`
    what format specifier can I use for this? is their anything in      `<string>` that lets me do this?
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `C++` has no control over what the user is allowed to enter via the standard input (`std::cin`). All you can do is complain if they give you spaces or maybe ignore them depending on what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to ignore the whitespaces. My program is behaving unexpectedly when spaces are between 2 strings. Unexpectedly unwanted behavior. So I want to ignore the spaces and get only the 1st string to pass to my other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::noskipws` to disable automatic skipping of whitespace prior to formatted input:

```
if (std::cin >> std::noskipws >> yy) {
    std::cout << "read '" << yy << "'\n";
}
```

If the user enters spaces prior to the string it will be an error as no word could be successfully read.